# Running a stored procedure with multiple values within the parameter

Tags: mysql, loops, stored-procedures, parameters

So I have a stored procedure-

CALL usp_ExperienceJobTitleClassifications( _experience_id , _involvedPartyID , status_id );

and a separate table with experience_ids and _involvedPartyIDs.

I would like o run the SP for a list of experience_ids and corresponding _involvedPartyID. Is this possible?

I have tried setting variable lists, however my issue with that is ensuring the experience_id and _involvedPartyID correlates. In addition I cant seem to pass more than one variable through to the SP at a time.

I know I could do a loop through all the records however performance on that is bad since I have 300k records to process.

Please assist

Comment: Please add your procedure code, sample data and expected outcome as text.

Comment: Create a table and store the values in there. The SP can then read that table.

Answer (score 1):

There is no 'simple' way to pass a list of things to a Stored Routine.

Here are some kludges.

- If you can turn construct a commalist of the values *and* use them only in a `WHERE` test, this works somewhat nicely:

  ```
  CALL foo('red,blue,pink')

  CREATE PROCEDURE foo(_list VARCHAR(100))
  ...
      SELECT ...
          WHERE FIND_IN_SET(mycolor, _list)
  ```
- It would be possible, but ugly, to write a loop in the SP to break apart a list (cf `SUBSTRING_INDEX()`) and act on each item.
- Build a table with the list of things, then use JOINs to get and/or compare the values.  I used this technique very effectively when I needed to pass a list of dozens of things, but the server was 80ms away.  (Dozens of 80ms delays was much slower than a few extra SQLs to build and populate the table -- via a single 'batched' `INSERT`.)

Since your use case involves pairs of values, the last kludge may be best.